# Java - Trim string after newline

Tags: java

My string is say :

```
str1="ash
def";
```

I want to remove anything after the newline so my desired string would be only `"ash"`.

How do I do this, One thing could be I could trim this and then substring it . Any other ways which I can do this.

Thanks

Comment: try doing split. str1.split("\n"); this will return an array of string. Simply use the first element.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(str1.split("\n")[0]);
```

This will split your string at first new line character and return first substring i.e. before `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring

```
String firstPart = str1.substring(0, str1.indexOf('\n'));
System.out.println(firstPart);
```

in contrast to

```
str.split("\n")[0]
```

the substring approach is faster, because

- split uses regexp to find the delimiter
- split creates at least 3 new objects. The returned array and the strings at the array indexes 0 and 1, but you only need the string at 0.

If your new line is `\n\r` then use the overloaded `String.indexOf(String)`

```
String str1 = "ash\n\rdef";
System.out.println(str1.substring(0, str1.indexOf("\n\r")));
```

Comment: Ok yeah thanks for this any idea how i could incorporate both `\n` and `\r` in this..?

Answer (score 1):

split by `\n` and select the first element

```
str.split("\n")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is another way to do this:

```
StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer("ash\ndef","\n");

System.out.println(st.nextToken());
```

and as you might be knowing you need to `import java.util.*;`